# Best practice in scaling angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I have been working on an AngularJs application which potentially can grow large in term content, views, templates and controllers. I really enjoyed the flexibility of angularjs. I could create new page very fast. Very stable and cross browsers. It's really powerful. However, since AngularJs does not have lazy loading feature and other lacks, I face challenge to make application scale. I am trying to share my issue here and hope, someone could tell me the right way to solve them:

### Multiple templates with different styles and controllers

The issue that I am facing here is how to be able to manage templates, css, controllers efficiently. I have hard time managing CSS as all of the them needed to be loaded at once. If I were using server side template (e.g. php, jsp), I could selectively load different CSS on different pages.

What I am thinking to do is to separate my application to small applications. I am then facing an issue of routing between them since my application is not completely separated. Managing multiple index.html files could be tedious as there will be quite a bit of duplication on index.html structure itself (event though I share directives and controllers).

A promising option would be to use ui-router instead of ng-route, but ui-route is still under development and it doesn't help with CSS and controller getting larger issues.

### Hiding application feature which is not accessible to particular user

Again since all controllers need to be loaded at once, beautifier minified javascript is still giving out a lot of information. If I would like certain features to be available to certain users, user may be able to figured it out that. Actually, obvious example would be that if I had a feature that will be available on a certain date, but I don't want to deploy new application at that time, I need to ship my modified controller. User can still see that the feature is contained in the code.

### Multiple layers of HTTP requests

Though, I tried my best to use resolve / asynchronous http request as much as possible, I am still end up with several layers (synchronous) of HTTP requests. If I remembered correctly, this is an example:

1. Browser load HTML
2. Browser load CSS / Javascript /start downloading some images
3. Resolve requests (user check, lookup fields data, page data, etc)
4. Request for views (partials)

5.1. Within the view, directives are loading template from templateUrl

5.2. Controller may send request for additional data (special case)

Some of my complex page may contain other images (e.g. in the directives, ng-includes, etc) which will be loaded after.

It takes about 1 second now for my first page to load. (though, the benchmark is not reliable, I do have fairly fast internet and my application is serving from AWS).

### Error messages (and other messages)

There are many error messages for our applications. I have a message file list all error messages (mostly input validation errors). This file grows big and everything needs to be loaded.

We have tried back end solution (e.g. our resource API returning error message). However, in many cases, API does not return the right message that we want to display or the message contains HTML (which I can think of ng-show/ng-hide or ng-html-bind...).

### Runtime vs build time configuration

We have dev, stage, and production which in each environment needs different configuration. For example, google analytic id, turn on and off dev mode (e.g. dev helpers).

My ugly solution now is that configuration file is generated and injected into index.html at during server starts. (Now, if I plan to separate applications, then I need to make it inject configuration into all of them... which probably be fine....)

### SEO

I read a lot of information regarding to SEO. At most part of my application is not for search, however, I would like first page and couples other to be crawled. Since we use Java on over server side, HtmlUnit is a pain and I couldn't get it to render page properly. Now, I am generating static snapshot by using grunt-html-snapshot which works for now since my content pages are static. But, I could see the problem with dynamic contents which we need to support in the future.

We may need to use 3rd party SEO or add node.js so that I can use phantom.js to create snapshot dynamically.

Our application works with some patch here and there (I felt it is not so beautiful). Please share your thought.

Comment: do you have a specific question?

Comment: Topic I highlighted are questions. I tried to explain the issue I am facing. And would like to see what are the options/how do other people do. (e.g. for each topic, the question is "How do you solve this issue?"). Thanks.

Comment: I'd add a tl;dr paragraph.

Comment: You probably already have read tons of material about angular, but I will add one more resource for you - free ng-cookbook http://ng-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/ng-cookbook.pdf You may be interested in chapters 6 or 13

Comment: Brian Ford also has a post discussing huge apps here: http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps.html. The question(s) are so broad that it is difficult to provide a concrete answer.